# create a variable with SSMS in dax

Tags: sql, ssms, dax

I want to put in a variable the sum of sales.
example:

```
var myvariable = 
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE('Internet Sales',"Internet Sales",'Internet Sales'[Internet Total Sales])
```

I am just getting an error from the SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myvariable = SUMMARIZE('Internet Sales' ,"Internet Sales",'Internet Sales'[Internet Total Sales]) 
evaluate myvariable
```